# What is the difference between dual sim active and dual sim stand-by?

Tags: internet, mobile-network, sony-xperia, dual-sim

I am Using Sony Xperia Tipo Dual, which is Dual Sim Smartphone, but When i use internet from SIM 1 using Network Mode = GSM only or WCDMA/ GSM the another SIM's says NO NETWORK. When i deactivate my Internet i receive message's from my Network operator that you got missed calls from these numbers. GSMArena says My phone is no dual stand-by.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are actually three types of dual SIM phones.

- Dual SIM Standby (DSS): Only one SIM can be used at a time, 1 radio chip. The phone has single IMEI number.
- Dual SIM Dual Standby (DSDS): Two SIMs can be used at a time, but if one opens a call or data connection, the other is offline. The phone has two different IMEI numbers.
- Dual SIM Active (or sometimes Dual SIM Dual Active) (DSA/DSDA): Two SIMs can be used at a time, 2 radio chips. This enables both SIMs to open calls and/or data connection. The phone has two different IMEI numbers.

Since your phone is mentioned as "No dual standby", it means it's a DSS-phone, which allows only one open connection at a time.

Answer (score 4):

Dual Sim standby : If you are talking in `Sim A` when someone calls to `Sim B` then they will hear `Sim B` is not reachable. You wont get prompted

Dual Sim Active : If you are talking in `Sim A` when someone calls to `Sim B` then they will hear your call is on waiting. You will get prompted and you can place the current call in hold and answer the new call.

But you should be able to receive call or make calls on both sim when you use internet.

GSM arena confirms Xperia Tipo is no dual standby meaning when you are using one sim to make phone call/ using data the other sim gets off. However, unlike many dual sim phones, in Xperia Tipo both the sim slot supports 3g sim.

Comment: no I able to receive & make call only with the Sim A from this i am using mobile data. When i stop using internet after few seconds the signal of sim B appears.

Comment: try swapping the sim and check

Comment: i have done this many times. it might be due to single IMEI no. when is type *#06#

Comment: No it should work even though you are using internet in one sim.

Comment: this is really irritating. because of this i cant even get any urgent calls. Thank god i have Missed call alerts.

Comment: Thanks. "But you should be able to receive call or make calls on both sim when you use internet." Do you mean the two SIM cards can't be used for voice calls at the same time, but can be used at the same time for VoIP over data or wifi? Regardless of whicy type of Dual Sim?

Answer (score 0):

I think the selected answer does  a good job of expressing the limitations/advantages of each type of dual sim you might encounter so I instead would like to suggest a work around so you don't miss calls when the one sim is in use and the  other becomes inactive.

If you setup call forwarding for each number when you're unreachable so that number 1 forwards to number 2 and number 2 forwards to number 1. Now setup both numbers with call waiting. You now shouldn't  miss a call when on the other line and you should be alerted when you have incoming calls waiting whether redirected or not.

A downside is that you'll get charged by your carrier for incoming routed calls. It's also worth noting that if one sim is roaming you may be charged at roaming rates for incoming re-routed calls.

What happens when phone is off and therefore both sims are unreachable? I don't know, I'd hope/expect the networks could detect such an occurrence and not allow an infinite redirect. Maybe someone here knows and can chime in?

Hope this helps