# Make a phone call in one SIM and simultaneously browse with the other

Tags: calls, data-connection, wifi-tethering, dual-sim

I have a Samsung Galaxy S10e SM-G970F that I'd like to use for phone calls and simultaneously as an hotspot (WiFi tethering) to browse from my laptop.

The phone has 2 sim cards.

I'm unable to make a phone call in one sim and simultaneously browse with the other.

As soon as a phone call begins in SIM1, the data connection drops in SIM2.

I tried many different combinations settings of:

- VoLTE calls SIM 1/2
- Allow all SIMs to use data in calls
- Dual SIM always on

I also tried switching "Calls" and "Mobile data" between the 2 SIMs.

So far no luck. Please, do you have any tips to achieve what I need?

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to have two data connections at the same time (one for VoLTE call the other for the hotspot). Have you tried to restrict the "call SIM" to 2G or 3G and disable data (assuming 2G and/or 3G is still available where you live)?

Comment: Good idea but no luck. I set SIM1 to 2G. SIM2 is used for data and right to its signal symbol I see the 4G+ symbol. As soon as I make a call with SIM1, the 4G+ symbol disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GSM Arena](https://m.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s10e-9537.php#sm-g970f/ds) says your phone has SIMs in DSDS mode

To achieve what you want you need a phone with SIMs in DSDA mode

See [What is the difference between dual sim active and dual sim stand-by?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/69045/131553)

So, sorry, you won't be able to achieve what you want with your phone.

---

For reference:

- From the [standards for dual SIMs on GSM networks](https://www.gsma.com/newsroom/wp-content/uploads//TS.37-v4.0.pdf)

> **Dual SIM Dual Standby (DSDS)**: both SIMs can be used for idle-mode network
> connection, but when a radio connection is active the second connection is disabled.
> As in the passive case, the SIMs in a DSDS device share a single transceiver.
> Through time multiplexing two radio connections are maintained in idle mode. When in-call on one network it is no longer possible to maintain radio connection to the second network, hence that connection is unavailable for the duration of the call.
> Registration to the second network is maintained

> **Dual SIM Dual Active (DSDA)**: both SIMs can be used in both idle and connected
> modes. Each SIM has a dedicated transceiver, meaning that there are no
> interdependencies on idle or connected mode operation at the modem level. Note
> that in some DSDA devices the second transceiver may be 2G-only.

- [5G on DSDS phones is expected in Android 12 phones](https://9to5google.com/2021/02/22/android-12-pixel-5g-dsds/amp/)